# Remove attribute from creating a product

Tags: magento2, attributes

How can I remove for example "color" from my creating product page without removing it from the store (just removing it in new product page)

Comment: You can remove it from required attribute set then this color option will not show during product creation.

Comment: Where can I do this ?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Login to admin
Step 2: Goto Store -> Attribute sets
[image]
Step 3: Edit the attribute set which you are using for products
[image]
Step 4: Then remove the color attribute by dragging the color attribute to right side then save.

Comment: Welcome! Happy Coding.